# When using Transmit Security, Can I use the WebAuthn SDK to build backchannel authentication flows?

Tags: authentication, sdk, identity, webauthn

What are other capabilities for WebAuthn SDK for backchannel authentication flows?

Curious to see if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - in fact there are two options, one is already available and the other will be released towards the end of 2022.

The first one leans on the cross device authentication flows. As described in the guides https://developer.transmitsecurity.com/guides/webauthn/sample_flow_sdk/#1-initiate-cross-device-flow - the APIs allow you to start a flow on one device and continue on another device.
While the guide focuses on a "desktop to mobile" flow, you could in fact use a backend to initiate the cross device flow, and otherwise follow the above guide:

1. Calling https://developer.transmitsecurity.com/openapi/webauthn/auth-session/#operation/startUnauthorizedSession and obtain an `auth_session_id`
2. Use this `auth_session_id` as part of a message to invoke the front authentication (send an SMS, etc) - which is performed according to the guide (this is the part described as "mobile" in the guide)
3. Have the backend poll on the `auth_session_id` using https://developer.transmitsecurity.com/openapi/webauthn/auth-session/#operation/getSessionStatus

As mentioned, we are soon releasing a CIBA API that will allow performing this in an OIDC compliant way. We will of course release a guide for this as well.